# How to prevent redux-form Field events from triggering state check in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form v6.5.0. I have a RecordFormPage component with a RecordForm component. The RecordForm  binds to redux-form

```
RecordForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'recordform'
})(RecordForm);
```

The RecordFormPage component connects to redux store

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log('state check on FormPage'); //every event in RecordForm checks state.
    return {
        record: state.records.record
    };
}
```

It renders the RecordForm component like this

```
<RecordForm onSubmit={ this.saveRecord } />
```

I initially had `initialValues={ this.props.record }` but for debugging perposes removed it.

Now, my question is;

is it expected / desired behaviour that on every Field event in RecordForm (focus, keypress etc) the RecordFormPage mapStateToProps is called? Can it be prevented? I would think it's unnecessary since the form is detached from the store.

Answer (score 3):

In short: this is how `react-redux` works, i.e. your `connect` prop functions `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `mergeProps` are essentially called each and every time the state of the redux store changes.

There are some rudimentary optimizations baked into `connect`, but if you want to optimize it further, you need to utilize [the `options` argument of `connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). It provides you with four equality check functions; `areStatesEqual`, `areOwnPropsEqual`, `areStatePropsEqual` and `areMergedPropsEqual`, that you can use to avoid unnecessary calls to the `connect` prop functions and thus to `render`.

In your case you could do something like this:

```js
const isRecordUnchanged = (prev, next) => {
  return prev.records.record === next.records.record
}

const connectOptions = { areStatesEqual: isRecordUnchanged }

@connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, connectOptions)
```

Remember that changing these equality checkers may lead to some funky behaviors if for example you use `areStatesEqual` to check only a small slice of the store state for equality, but your `mapStateToProps` deals with state outside the scope of that slice you use to check equality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your explanation, it does makes things clear to me I didn't know. I do still think the state/store shouldn't be touched when a field gets focus and changes a redux-form specific property (.touched). It has nothing to do with the store or (record)state.

Comment: The name of the library is `redux-form` and the convenience of storing form state in the redux store trades off with the inconvenience of having every small action in the form to trigger the cascade of store-related function calls.  The challenge in software engineering is to choose the right tech with the correct pros and cons to suit your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll hold the trade off against the benefit (basically the ease of validations in the case of redux-form.)